# Adding Back Button to Navigation Bar Doesn't Work

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar

I've added a navigation bar to my view controller and added text to the Back Button option under Attributes Inspector but I'm not getting a back button when I run the app.

Picture of the setting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xfdc.jpg

Picture of the storyboard: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGEsY.jpg

Picture of app when I run: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV7Mh.jpg

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you presenting your view controller? in order to get a back button you should push it

Comment: @dminones I am using a "Show (e.g. Push) segue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your View Controller should be embedded in a navigation Controller. By doing this a back button is added by default in the View Controller.

Comment: I tried to do this. I manually performed a segue to a navigation controller and it crashes on me without any error msg just (lldb), any thing to look out for when performing manual segue to a navigation view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Embedded your `controller` in `UINavigationController` and then do your operation `Push or pop or etc`

```
 Controller * objController = [[Controller alloc] initWithNibName:@“controllernib” bundle:nil];
UINavigationController * navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: objController];
```